# Trouble converting yaml file to toml file

Tags: yaml, toml

I am trying to convert a yaml file into a toml file in python3.

My plan is to use `toml.dumps()` which expects a dictionary, then write to an output file.

I need to be able to match the input toml requirements for a tool that I need to plug into.
This tool expects inline tables at certain instances like this:

```
[states.Started]
outputs = { on = true, running = false }
[[states.Started.transitions]]
inputs = { go = true }
target = "Running"
```

I understand how to generate the tables [] and array of tables [[]] but I am having a hard time figuring out how to create the inline tables.

TOML documentation says that inline tables are the same as tables. So for example, with the array of tables above (states.Started.Transitions) I figured inputs would be a table within the overall list, however the TOML format will break it into separate tables at the output.

Can anyone help me figure out how to configure my dictionary to output the inline table?

EDIT***

I am not sure I fully understand what I am doing wrong. Here is my code

```
table = {'a':5,'b':3}

inline_table = toml.TomlDecoder().get_empty_inline_table()

inline_table['Values'] = table

encoder = toml.TomlPreserveInlineDictEncoder()
toml_config = toml.dumps(inline_table,encoder = encoder)
```

however this does not create an inline table, but a regular table in the output.

```
[Values]
a = 5
b = 3
```

Comment: Hint: Comment on my answer if you need additional guidance, I don't get a notification if you simply edit your question. You're making the wrong table an inline table – `table` must be inline, not the root table containing `Values`!

Answer (score 1):

> This tool expects inline tables at certain instances like this

Then it is not a TOML tool. As you discovered yourself, inline tables are semantically equivalent to normal tables, so if the tool conforms to the TOML specification, it must not care whether the tables are inline or not. If it does, this is not a TOML question.

That being said, you can create the dicts that should become inline tables via

```py
TomlDecoder().get_empty_inline_table()
```

The returned object is a dict subclass and can be used as such.

When you finished creating your structure, use `TomlPreserveInlineDictEncoder` for dumping and don't ask why this is suddenly called `InlineDict` instead of `InlineTable`.